# How to subtract from each date a corresponding value?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes. These continue until 2021 but the second has one observation per day and the first has many. How could I subtract the cost per day from the price given that the dataframes are not equal in length?

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-07-01 | 123.9 |
| 2019-07-01 | 126.7 |
| 2019-07-01 | 124.9 |
| 2019-07-01 | 129.9 |

| Date | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-07-01 | 110.1 |
| 2019-07-02 | 115.3 |

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also provide the desired output for your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `merge` and subtract the two columns

```
res <- transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 'Date'), diff = Price - Cost)
res

#        Date Price  Cost diff
#1 2019-07-01 123.9 110.1 13.8
#2 2019-07-01 126.7 110.1 16.6
#3 2019-07-01 124.9 110.1 14.8
#4 2019-07-01 129.9 110.1 19.8
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not clear how the desired output shall look like. Saying the dataframe with `Price` is called `df_price` and the one with `Cost`  `df_cost`, then the desired output, so called `df` with the difference in `Desired`:

```
df_price <- data.frame(Date = c("2019-07-01","2019-07-01","2019-07-01","2019-07-01"),
                       Price = c(123.9,126.7,124.9,129.9))

df_cost <- data.frame(Date = c("2019-07-01","2019-07-02"),
                      Cost = c(110.1,115.3))

df <- left_join(df_price, df_cost, by = "Date") %>%
  mutate(Desired = Price - Cost)
```

Output:

```
        Date Price  Cost Desired
1 2019-07-01 123.9 110.1    13.8
2 2019-07-01 126.7 110.1    16.6
3 2019-07-01 124.9 110.1    14.8
4 2019-07-01 129.9 110.1    19.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, diff := Price - Cost, on = 'Date']
```

-output

```
 df1
         Date Price diff
1: 2019-07-01 123.9 13.8
2: 2019-07-01 126.7 16.6
3: 2019-07-01 124.9 14.8
4: 2019-07-01 129.9 19.8
```